# Conversion string to float using simple_form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi,
I have the following slim template in my RoR application:

```
= simple_form_for(@request) do |f|
  = f. input :amount, required: true, label: 'Amount'
```

Currently, if user input is "100,12" - the digits after decimal point are discarded, which is not correct. But if "100.12" - the value converted to float, which is correct.

The questions is: How to override the field format in order to convert input value to float for both "100,12" and "100.12" input values.

It seems to me the answer is somewhere in:

*config/initializers/simple_form.rb*

*config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb*

*config/locales/simple_form.en.yml*

But I could not find a specific implementation.

Thank you for advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced the issue before. Not only the front-end needs to adapt the comma as the decimal separator but also the back-end. Follow the guide here.

https://blog.makandra.com/2010/03/how-to-use-the-comma-as-decimal-separator-in-activerecord-columns-and-text-fields/